# getting error while changing orientation of emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android. I created a main.xml file like

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@android:color/white"
     android:paddingTop="5dp"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"       
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mazarslogo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        ....

    </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

This file is in my res/layout/main.xml folder. Now i create a new folder named layout-land and put a file main.xml in it. i.e. res/layout-land/main.xml, and put the following code in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"       
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mazarslogo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //---the two buttons are wired to the same event handler---
        Button btn_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login );
        btn_login.setOnClickListener(btnListener);

         .....

    } //end of onCreate()

} //end of class MainActivity
```

But now when i run the project, the project open in portrait mode, but when i press ctrl+F11 to change the orientation of the emulator then i get error.

[image]

Here is the portrait mode pic

[image]

Why i am getting this error in landscape  mode? What i am doing wrong?

Thanks

**Edit
-------------------------------------------------------------------**

Here is my working res/layout-land/main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/background"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:padding="1dip"
android:orientation="horizontal" > >

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="20dip"
    android:paddingRight="20dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"       
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mazarslogo" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_login"                 
                android:text="@string/login"                
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_aboutUs"                           
                android:text="@string/aboutUs"                  
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
             <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_contactUs"                 
                android:text="@string/contactUs"            
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_exit"                  
                android:text="@string/exit"         
                android:textSize="12sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>        
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Here you button in xml file...

Comment: @Basit Please post your app logcat.

Comment: this likes your `land` xml forget `RelativeLayout` which in your `port`, if the button `R.id.btn_login` in this `RelativeLayout` layout, may be throw the `NullPointerException`, also can you paste your logcate ?

Comment: where is button in this file res/layout-land/main.xml?

Comment: post your logcat error message.

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur Nirali yes you people are right. I was missing putting buttons in my `res/layout-land/main.xml` file. So what was happening that when i changed the orientation, then it was unable to find button in my class file i.e. `Button btn_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login );`. This was throwing exception. After putting buttons in my layout-land/main.xml file, things start working. Thanks to you people :)

Comment: Agree with :idiottiger and also if its is there, check the Button IDS are given and they are same in both files.

Comment: @idiottiger No, I didn't put Relative layout in my layout-land/main.xml file but it is still working.I used table layout instead of Relative layout

Comment: @all  You all can check my edit. The two main.xml files are not exactly same. I use Table lay out instead of relative and it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing keep in mind both xml should be with same data either imageview ,button,or layout there id should also be same for both layout  for potrait and  lancaspe layout and u have need to add following thing in menifest in activtiy

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```